# UWP + DirectX11: Mouse movement

Tags: uwp, directx-11

I am writing a game engine for UWP in C++, using DX11. I am using the `CoreWindow` input events to relay input to the game engine (buttons, keys and mouse movement). However, I have run into problems with creating an FPS camera. What I want to do is to zero the mouse cursor on the center of the screen and then read any movement as relative to that point so I can determine the camera view rotation.

This has proven nearly impossible... First off, setting the mouse cursor position is not possible since `PointerPosition` on `CoreWindow` is read-only (something I have been cursing Microsoft for now a couple of hours, why do they keep putting these stupid blockades up for us devs?). And I need to be able to zero, otherwise I will be limited by the screen.

DXInput does not seem to work, Intellisense recognizes the interfaces, but the compiler does not, which is super-weird to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested on my PC and I am able to set `PointerPosition` on `CoreWindow` as follows:

```
CoreWindow^ window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
window->PointerPosition = Point(10, 10);
```

The pointer then actually moves to the given location within the window as expected.

Comment: Ah.. so not using "new Point(10, 10)" and instead going with just "Point(10, 10)" works. That's peculiar, but solves it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, C++ never fails to surprise :-D . Happy coding!